# Syntax shortcut for calling generic methods

Tags: c#, generics

I just found out that in C# the following will compile

`public void Exec<T>(T t) => Console.WriteLine(t.ToString());`
and you can call it like

```
Exec(1);
Exec(new SomeClass());
```

What I find interesting is that you can omit the parameter type in the brackets and still get type safety (if you added constraints to the T).  Is this a new feature?  This seems nifty

Comment: [when c# generics introduced](https://www.bing.com/search?q=when+c%23+generics+introduced&form=EDGEAR&qs=PF&cvid=cab109dec62b4149803d9b14e51130d2&cc=US&setlang=en-US)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is called *generic type inference* ([see here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/generic-methods)). The compiler can see you are passing in an `int` or a `SomeClass` so it *infers* the generic type. Take this example:

```
public void DoStuff<T, U>(T param1, U, param2) { ... }
```

You can call it like this:

```
DoStuff(1, "hello");
```

In fact, you've probably already used this feature without even realising it. All of the Linq methods are generically typed, so any time you've used `Where`, `Count` or `Select` for example, you could have specified the types. Now can you imagine how ugly that code would look? For example:

```
var list = new List<string>();

var filteredList1 = list.Where<string>(s => s == "hello");
var filteredList2 = list.Where(s => s == "hello");
```

However, how about this:

```
public TOutput DoStuff<TInput, TOutput>(TInput param1) { ... }
```

If you call it without specifying the types, you are only allowing the compiler to *infer* the first generic type so you will get a compiler error:

> CS0411 The type arguments for method 'DoStuff(TInput)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.